# listener shows service with domain name

Tags: oracle

On Standby, when I run lsnrctl status I see

```
Service ".test.abc.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "drdb10c11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "drdb10c1.test.abc.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "drdb10c11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

The service with name and domain looks good, but why and how is a service coming up with only dot plus domain name - below are few parameters from the db. Please advise as to how to fix to get a service with only service name without domain name.

```
*.db_domain='test.abc.com'
*.db_name='db10c1'
*.db_unique_name='drdb10c1'
*.global_names=TRUE
*.instance_name='drdb10c11'
*.service_names='drdb10c1.test.abc.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

comment out `*.db_domain='test.abc.com'`
then only name will show up in service

Comment: And he would then have to adjust all of his tnsnames.ora files.  His question wasn't 'why does the domain name show up', it was 'why does this one entry have _only_ the domain name, without the database name'

Comment: yes EdStevens, I am trying why this service only domain name exists. I want to have 2 services one with db name and another with db plus domain name. If I remove domain name parameter then it wont create a service with db plus domain name which I need. From where is this service with only domain name coming up? How to bring up service with only db name?